# Best way to backup Rundeck

Tags: backup, database-backups, rundeck, backup-strategies

I need your help on a subject.

I need to perform a backup of our Rundeck system and send it to a server in the GCP, but there are more than 90GB of information and I don't know how to make this backup.

All my attempts to compress using gzip, bzip2, xz and rsync have failed, the error is basically because the file is too big.

What would be the best way to perform the backup?

Could you give me suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html) guide. Also, as a tip: keep out the execution logs from your project export, to gain space in your files.

Comment: Friends, good afternoon.

Thanks for the tips and advice, but what happens, we have approximately 20000 jobs running and the guide presented by the Rundeck team itself was not very clear to me.

The problem is by no means the guide presented, but me. I really lack stuff and knowledge about the rundeck, not least because I was introduced to this system recently.

So my doubts about the best way to perform the backup.