# Rundeck MariaDB hot backup

Tags: rundeck

On rundeck [backup guide](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html#backup), noted that is mandatory to stop rundeck to take full backup when using data file. Now, that guide don't show any secure method to backup full rundeck instance (rundeck server + database) when using MariaDB, PostgreSQL, or any supported database as a backend.

In a real production scenario, not seems to be possible to stop rdeck on a daily basis.

Can anybody share best pratices to take a hot full backup on rdeck installation without stop rdeck?
Is there any secure and supported way to achive a full consistent rdeck projects and jobs definitions and database on a daily basis ?

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60459184/best-way-to-backup-rundeck), answer is not clear, because question don't describe what kinbd of backend are used.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation suggests the instance shutdown because some execution could be active, and that means a potentially active transaction in the middle of the "hot backup process" which means a potential data corruption in your backup. Is the safest way to backup your database.

If you want to do a "hot" backup you can [export](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/project-archive.html#export-archive) your projects (with all content, including jobs) and [keys](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html#export-import-keys).